# Partition Image into 9 equal or nearly equal partitions: Matlab

Tags: arrays, image, matlab

I need to partition an image to 9 equal or nearly equal partitions and store each of the partition into an array. So, the end result would be like array of arrays where each element of an array is a 2x2 array representing a partition of image. So far, I have come up with the following code

```
function [ outputImageRectangles ] = getImagePartitions( inputImage )
%Write the code to partition image into 9 equal or nearly equal size
%rectangles
[height, width] = size(inputImage);
partitions = zeros(3,3);
for i=0:2
    for j=0:2
        loweri = floor(i*height/3)+1;
        higheri = floor((i+1)*height/3);
        lowerj = floor(j*width/3)+1;
        higherj = floor((j+1)*width/3);
        x = i+1;
        y = j+1;
        loweri
        higheri
        lowerj
        higherj

        partitions(x,y,:,:) = inputImage(loweri:higheri, lowerj:higherj);
    end
end
outputImageRectangles = partitions;

end
```

I assume that process of partitioning works fine but i have problems storing each partition into an array element. I am very new to matlab and just trying to get a grip on it. I also read a bit about cell arrays which can contain another array as an array element. So far, this code gives me errors on

```
 partitions(x,y,:,:) = inputImage(loweri:higheri, lowerj:higherj);
```

obviously because there are array dimensions mismatch. My question is how to perform this task without degrading the performance too much? Performance is critical because this function will be called for more than 12000 images.

Comment: I dont understand the purpose of the 4D indexing of `partitions`, could you explain further? wouldn't the end result be 9 images, potentially different sized? The best way to store this is a cell array, as `partitions{x,y}=...`, unless that 4D means something that I am missing

Comment: Its 4D because I don't know how to do it right. I tried `partitions(x,y,:)` and still got the error.

Comment: And have you tried what I suggested?

Comment: @AnderBiguri Yes, that worked for me. thanks

Comment: is there a difference of performance b/w cell arrays and normal arrays?

Comment: Depends on how good your code is. There are a lot of functions to deal with cells, but in the end, if your matrices have different size, you dont really have an option

Comment: Basically the size of one image is fixed and it needs to be partitioned and we can come up with fixed size blocks if we have to. I mean if it impacts the performance two much. In that case we my forget the code elegance and just look at corner cases where last block may have to contain additional one or two pixels in row/column if image array is not perfect multiple of 3

Comment: As We do not have you whole code, this is a call for you to make. Try options, time them and decide it yourself.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just use a cell array. As your subblocks are not the same size, its the best option to store the data.

```
partitions{x,y} = inputImage(loweri:higheri, lowerj:higherj);
```

Answer (score -1):

You can try this out

```
function [ outputImageRectangles ] = getImagePartitions( inputImage )
[height, width] = size(inputImage);
for i=0:2
    for j=0:2
        loweri = floor((i*height)/3)+1;
        higheri = floor((i+1)*height/3);
        lowerj = floor(j*width/3)+1;
        higherj = floor((j+1)*width/3);
        x = i+1;
        y = j+1;

        partitions{x,y} = inputImage(loweri:higheri, lowerj:higherj);
    end
end
outputImageRectangles = partitions;
```

Comment: @downvoter, would you care to please leave a comment?

Comment: I didn't downvote, but `partitions` now is a 4D cell array where this answer indexes into the cell array like a 2D array.  This code will crash on the first time `partiions{x,y}` is being run.

Comment: I havent downvoted, but this is literally a copy paste of my answer and OPs code, you added no extra information

Comment: Well i did answer before you... Did a little mistake which i corrected later